# C++ reference can be assignable?

Tags: c++, reference, variable-assignment, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I've been messing with references wrapped in container classes. Why is the following code legal and appear to behave correctly?

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo( int i ) : i_( i ) {}
  int i_;
};

class FooWrapper
{
public:
  FooWrapper( Foo& foo ) : foo_( foo ) {}
  Foo& foo_;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Foo foo( 42 );
  FooWrapper fw( foo );
  FooWrapper fw2 = fw;
  std::cout << fw2.foo_.i_ << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In the absence of an explicit `operator=`, I believe C++ does a memberwise copy. So when I do `FooWrapper fw2 = fw;`, is this not two operations: (1) create `FooWrapper fw` with a default ctor followed by (2) assignment from `fw` to `fw2`? I'm sure this isn't happening, because a reference can't be created uninitialized, so is the creation of `fw2` actually treated as a copy construction?

I'm sometimes unclear on the roles of copy construction vs. assignment; they seem to bleed into each other sometimes, as in this example, but there's probably some rule I'm unaware of. I'd be grateful for an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line below, you are constructing `fw2` by making it a copy of `fw`. That is, you are invoking the copy-constructor.

```
FooWrapper fw2 = fw;
```

**Example**

Here is an ([online](http://cpp.sh/5fyz)) example on how [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment), and [move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) (from C++11) are invoked.

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    foo() {std::cout << "Default constructor" << '\n';}
    foo(foo const&) {std::cout << "Copy constructor" << '\n';}
    foo& operator=(foo const&) {std::cout << "Copy assignment operator" << '\n'; return *this; }
    foo& operator=(foo &&) {std::cout << "Move assignment operator" << '\n'; return *this; }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    foo a;            // Default constructor
    foo b = a;        // Copy constructor
    foo c;            // Default constructor
    c = b;            // Copy assignment operator
    b = std::move(c); // Move assignment operator
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Despite the `=` in the syntax, `FooWrapper fw2 = fw;` copy constructs `fw2` (using the copy constructor). Neither default construction nor assignment is involved at all.

And to answer the question in the title: no, references cannot be assigned. If you wrote code that attempted to actually default construct or assign a `FooWrapper`, such as:

```
FooWrapper fw2;
fw2 = fw;
```

...this would fail. Officially, only a "diagnostic" is required. Unofficially, every compiler I know of would/will refuse to compile it.

Answer (score 3):

This initialization actually calls the copy constructor.
`FooWrapper fw2 = fw;`
and is equivalent to
`FooWrapper fw2(fw);`

The implicitly defined copy constructor doesn't need to create an uninitialized reference

For reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Comment: yes that's what I meant. Changed the wording to `implicitly defined copy constructor`

Comment: wording also comes to the fact that nowadays one can explicitly asks the compiler to generate a copy constructor via the `default` keyword:
`class_name ( const class_name & ) = default;`